# List View in Flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, mobile, flutter-layout, flutter-futurebuilder

I've been having trouble understanding how to correctly list of all the items from the API call, I have now made it to display the first from the list of the API, by adding the index [0] after the API response. I realize I can do that with the itemCount which I currently had it set at 1 since I can't seem to comprehend how to use the .length option that lists all of the item from the API. Here is the code:

API CALL:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:practice/models/jobs.dart';

Future<JobData> fetchJobs() async {
  final response = await http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
    // then parse the JSON.
    return JobData.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body)[0]);
  } else {
    // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
    // then throw an exception.
    throw Exception('Failed to load jobs');
  }
}
```

THE JOB MODEL:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class JobData extends ChangeNotifier {
  final int userId;
  final int id;
  final String title;
  final String body;

  JobData({this.userId, this.id, this.title, this.body});

  factory JobData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return JobData(
      userId: json['userId'],
      id: json['id'],
      title: json['title'],
      body: json['body'],
    );
  }
}
```

AND THE WIDGET WHERE IT IS RENDERED:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:practice/models/jobs.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:practice/services/api_calls.dart';

class JobList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _JobListState createState() => _JobListState();
}

class _JobListState extends State<JobList> {
  Future<JobData> futureJobs;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureJobs = fetchJobs();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
      children: [
        Text(
          'Today',
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 12.0,
        ),
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.grey[300],
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(12.0),
              topRight: Radius.circular(12.0),
            ),
          ),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0),
                child: Text(
                  'Jobs #1',
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                ),
              ),
              FlatButton(
                textColor: Colors.blue[700],
                minWidth: 0,
                child: Text('View'),
                onPressed: () {
                  
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(12.0),
              bottomRight: Radius.circular(12.0),
            ),
          ),
          child: Consumer<JobData>(
            builder: (context, jobData, child) {
              return SizedBox(
                height: 200,
                child: FutureBuilder<JobData>(
                  future: futureJobs,
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      return ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: 1,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                              children: [
                                Text('${snapshot.data.userId}',
                                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                                Text(
                                  '${snapshot.data.id}',
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  '${snapshot.data.title}',
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  '${snapshot.data.body}',
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                                ),
                              ],
                            );
                          });
                    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                      return Text("${snapshot.error}");
                    }

                    // By default, show a loading spinner.
                    return CircularProgressIndicator();
                  },
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 16.0,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Do you I need to make a list out of the returned API response first and then display it's length?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you want to show the first job only?

Comment: @Shanto I would like to show all 100 jobs from the API that I am calling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this..

```
Future<List<JobData>> fetchJobs() async {
List<JobData> jobs = new List();
final response = await http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
  // then parse the JSON.
  var jobsJson = jsonDecode(response.body);
  for(int i = 0; i < jobsJson.length; i++) {
    jobs.add(JobData.fromJson(jobsJson[i]));
  }
     return jobs;
  } else {
  // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
  // then throw an exception.
     throw Exception('Failed to load jobs');
  }
}
```

then..

```
Future<List<JobData>> futureJobs;
```

inside ListView

```
itemCount: futureJobs.length,
```

then take each job from `futureJobs` list using index and show in `ListView()`

Comment: It worked like charm, thank you! :) But was I right? I had to first make a list out of the data I received from the API call and then display it in the components? This is what you did, right?